# Proving these trigonometric sums $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\frac{2k^2\pi}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\left(\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}+1\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Can someone help me to prove that:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\frac{2k^2\pi}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\left(\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}+1\right)$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2k^2\pi}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\left(\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}+\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}+1\right)$$

Comment: These are formulas AD 361.18-19 in Gradshteyn's *Table of Integrals, Series and Products*. Is proof by citation an acceptable answer here? =)

Comment: @DavidH perhaps he is looking for more details

Comment: @DavidH, Yes, I'm expecting some more generic

Comment: A nice proof (In French) for this case here : http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~remy/SommesDeGauss.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Let $A = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2k^2\pi}{n}$ and $B = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\frac{2k^2\pi}{n}$ then we are looking to show:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{2\pi i k^2/n} = A + iB = e^{\tfrac{\pi i n}{2}}\sqrt{n}\tfrac{1+i}{2}  $$

I believe this is the [Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum)

---

I have seen the Gauss sum for primes $p$ but not necessarily for $n$.  However,

You know the absolute value because you can find the norm, i.e. multiply by the complex conjugate, or use Parseval Theorem

$$ \bigg|\bigg|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{2\pi i k^2/n}\bigg|\bigg|^2 = 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{2\pi i k^2/n} \times 
\overline{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{2\pi i k^2/n}}
= 1\cdot 1 + \dots 1 + \cdot 1 = n$$

The norm of our Gauss sum is $\sqrt{n}$ and we need to compute the sign.