# How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^n\sin\frac{n^2\pi}{4k}=(-1)^k\sqrt{k/2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, summation

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^n\sin\frac{n^2\pi}{4k}=(-1)^k\sqrt{k/2}$$

How to prove it without induction? Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: for $k=1$ we get $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ and not $-1$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I see nothing in the question that suggests the answer should be $-1$. Note that the right hand side is $\sqrt{k/2}$, not $\sqrt{k}$.

Comment: ok you are right

Comment: it's correct. please, calculate again.

Comment: Did you try an induction proof.

Comment: @Salahamam I don't want to prove by induction. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Salahamam I can not find/solve summation that is similar to this summation, so i don't want to prove by induction.

Comment: It's possible to estimate the sum via an integral

Comment: As first, try to use the symmetry by $(2k-n)^2=4k(k-n)+n^2$ to reduce the number of terms.

Comment: "without induction" is for wimps. Try proving it standing on one leg, with your hands tied on your back. Mathematics is for professionals, and professionals use professional tools, industrial strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^n\exp i \frac{n^2\pi}{4k} = \\
\sum_{n=1}^{2k}\exp i (\frac{n^2\pi}{4k} - n \pi) = \\
\sum_{n=1}^{2k}\exp i \frac{(n^2- 4 k n )\pi}{4k} = \\
\sum_{m=1}^{2k}\exp i \frac{((m- 2 k )^2 - 4k^2)\pi}{4k} = \\
\sum_{n=0}^{2k-1}\exp i \frac{(n^2 - 4k^2)\pi}{4k} = \\
(-1)^k - 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{2k}\exp i \frac{(n^2 - 4k^2)\pi}{4k} = \\
(-1)^k - 1 + (-1)^k  \sum_{n=1}^{2k}\exp i \frac{n^2 \pi}{4k} 
$$
with an index shift $n = m- 2 k$ as one step.
Now taking the imaginary part of S gives the desired 
$$R  = \sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^n\sin\frac{n^2\pi}{4k} =  (-1)^k  \sum_{n=1}^{2k}\sin \frac{n^2 \pi}{4k} 
$$

So we have for odd k only the odd terms:

$$R  =   - \sum_{n=1}^{k}\sin \frac{(2n -1)^2 \pi}{4k} = -\sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}
$$
and for even k only the even terms:
$$R  =   \sum_{n=1}^{k}\sin \frac{n^2 \pi}{k} = \sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}
$$
where the last summation result was shown  (see the answer in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895419/)), similar to Gauss's sum. (The summation for odd $k$ will work accordingly.)

The overall result is then 
$$R  =   (-1)^k \sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}
$$

Comment: how to show R = $\sqrt(k/2), (-1)sqrt(k/2)$ for odd and even.

Comment: oh, i see. I'm sorry.

Comment: i'm confuse. the R calculation for odd and even.

Comment: if k is even, $n^2\pi/(4k) = \pi/(4k), 2^2\pi/(4k),...$ i can not show it to your summation.

Comment: if k is odd, why can you calculate only n is odd. and if k is even, why can you calculate only even term.

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs Add the two equivalent sums for R above. The first has alternating signs for the even / odd terms, the second hasn't. So for k odd (even), only the odd (even) terms remain.

Comment: If k is even, the terms in the sum (only the even ones, see above) are $ \sin ((2 n)^2 \pi / 4k ) = \sin (n^2 \pi / k)$.

Comment: how to you know about it's alternating sign, I don't sure.

Comment: $\sin(n^2\pi/(4k))$ if $n^2$ is replaced by $n$, I know it, but it's $n^2$

Comment: How can I read more about this alternating sign?

Comment: I'm confuse about guass sum for R where k is odd and even.  I can not show to the RHS, I think guass sum must be used for only prime.
and k is odd, it's not a form of guass sum.