How to evaluate : $S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\left({\frac{2\pi k^2}{n}}\right)$
I need help to find :$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\left({\frac{2\pi k^2}{n}}\right)$$
This sum can be written in this form:\begin{align*}S&=\text{Re}\left({\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{\frac{2i\pi k^2}{n}}}\right) \\&= \text{Re}\left({\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k^2}}\right)\end{align*}
where $x=e^{\frac{2i\pi }{n}}$
Can this sum be calculated?
This question is from the book.SUMMATION OF SERIES COLLECTED BY L. B. W. JOLLEY, M.A. (CANTAB.), M.I.E.E.
Proplem 434
The answer was given as equal to: $$S=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\left({1+\sin\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)+\cos\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)}\right)$$

This is the real part of the quadratic Gauss sum $S(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ik^2}{n}}$. It can be shown by the use of truncated Poisson summation formula that
\begin{align*}
S(n)=\frac{1+i^{-n}}{1+i^{-1}}\sqrt n.
\end{align*}
Noting that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1+i^{-n}}{1+i^{-1}}=\frac{1}{2}\left({1+\sin\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)+\cos\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)}\right)+\frac{i}{2}
\left({1-\sin\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)+\cos\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)}\right),
\end{align*}
we obtain the sums
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2k^2\pi}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\left({1+\sin\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)+\cos\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)}\right)\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\frac{2k^2\pi}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\left({1-\sin\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)+\cos\left({\frac{n\pi}{2}}\right)}\right).
\end{align*}
For the derivation of $S(n)$ formula, see Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory.

Also seems to be the duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895419/proving-these-trigonometric-sums-sum-limits-k-0n-1-sin-frac2k2-pin?rq=1
